# INSERT statement in SQL Server - is it correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
insert into Employee_Document 
values(FristName, LastName, BeginWeek, EndWeek, 
       Hrs_Mon, hrs_tues, Hrs_Wed, Hrs_Thu, Hrs_Fri, Total_Hours,
       TaskDesc_Mon, TaskDesc_Tues, TaskDesc_Wed, TaskDesc_Thu, TaskDesc_Fri, '')

select 
   FristName, LastName, BeginWeek, EndWeek, 
   TotalHours where TimeSheetDate='31-12-2012' AS Hrs_Mon,'08:00:00',
   TotalHours where TimeSheetDate='02-01-2013' AS Hrs_Wed,
   TotalHours where TimeSheetDate='03-01-2013' AS Hrs_Thu,
   TotalHours where TimeSheetDate='04-01-2013' AS Hrs_Fri,
   TaskDescription where TimeSheetDate='31-12-2012' AS TaskDesc_Mon,
   TaskDescription where TimeSheetDate='02-01-2013' AS TaskDesc_Wed,
   TaskDescription where TimeSheetDate='03-01-2013' AS TaskDesc_Thu,
   TaskDescription where TimeSheetDate='04-01-2013' AS TaskDesc_Fri,'' 
from 
   vw_TSDailyTotalHoursTaskDesc)
```

Is there any wrong in this statement as I am new to SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand 2 things, what is `''` at the end of column list and what is '08:00:00' at the third line?

Comment: You should at least state what this query's result should be. If you don't do that, people cannot help you...

Comment: hi ,i want to insert values from one table to another where column names will not match. i want to split them using 'timesheetdate' column so that i can split them to specific column in another table.

Comment: And **does it work**? If not: is there an **error** (and if so: **WHAT** error) ??

Comment: I can see you wanna insert value in "Total_Hours" and select "TotalHours", which one is the right? I recommend you recheck the entire insert, compare the field and try again.

Answer (score 0):

(lol)

OK, first of all the keyword VALUES needs to be removed, basic insert syntax is either:

```
INSERT [INTO] tablename (column list...) VALUES (literals...)
```

or

```
INSERT [INTO] tablename (column list) SELECT...
```

As the above is the latter, just remove VALUES altogether.

Next, there just ain't no such column named '', cannot be (at the limit could be [''] if really perverse], sort that out.

Finally, I'm guessing what you're trying to do with this

```
TotalHours where TimeSheetDate='31-12-2012' AS Hrs_Mon,'08:00:00',
```

is probably something like

```
CASE WHEN TimeSheetDate='31-12-2012' THEN TotalHours ELSE '08:00:00' END AS Hrs_Mon,
```

or something??

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can see the only thing incorrect is that on the first line you have the word values which isn't required.